# Angular - issues with Promise Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, rest, api, promise

I have an issue trying to fetch members from an API. Apparently the request works properly but angular fails to fetch the result into members object or something like that. I don't really understand the error that it raise.

So far, it a basic application that just fetch the member from the API and should display them in an inline template.

Here is my service:

```
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { MEMBERS } from './../member-mock';
import { Member } from './../member';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class MemberService {
    private apiUrl = '../api/members';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    constructor(private http: Http){}
    members : Member[] = [];
    getMembers(){
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Member[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

And my component

```
import { ModalService } from './../Services/modal-service';
import { OrderService } from './../Services/order-service';
import { Member } from './../member';
import { MemberService } from './../Services/member-service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'member-pane',
  template: `
    <div class='order-pane'>
        <h2>Membres</h2>
        <ul class="">
        <li class="membre" *ngFor="let member of members">
            <b>{{member.prenom}} {{member.nom}}
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./member-pane.css']
})
export class MemberPaneComponent {
    constructor(private memberService: MemberService) { }

    members = this.memberService.getMembers();
}
```

And it raise the following error that I do not understand:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXWcP.jpg)

And finally here is the JSON returned by the API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1086,
        "prenom": "Mick",
        "nom": "Mal",
        "amount": 0,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1087,
        "prenom": "Loic",
        "nom": "Pal",
        "amount": 0,
        "total": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Still honing my angular2+ skills, but this line is bothering me `response => response.json().data as Member[]`. I feel like you are wrapping what is already an array. What if you just had `response => response.json().data`? That looks the closest to response.data with $http in 1.x..

Comment: Also, I've changed the angularjs tag to angular as AngularJS is for the 1.x straing, and AngularJS is for 2+. (AngularJS: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info), (Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info).

Answer (score 0):

Your response does not have a `data` property, but is an array, so you should return it as it is:

```ts
getMembers(){
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as Member[]) // remove 'data'
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and change getting the data from:

```ts
members = this.memberService.getMembers();
```

to

```ts
this.memberService.getMembers()
  .then(members => this.members = members)
```